# Stacking QGraphicsWidgets side by side

Tags: python, c++, qt, pyqt

I've created a widget that uses the QGraphicsFramework to draw items to a canvas. Currently, I use one QGraphicsScene to keep track of my items and a QGraphicsView to visualize the items in the scene. I am using PyQt, but this is really more of a general Qt question.

This is what I have. It's one QGrapicsView and one QGraphicsScene.

[image]

What I want, where it's all drawn on one QGraphicsView, with three QGrapicsWidgets.

[image]

The first problem is that I don't know Qt that well so I am not sure if I understand the concepts correctly. It is my understanding that a QGraphicsWidget inherits from the QGraphicsItem so that I can add many of them to the same scene while still being able to handle all the events internally.

The problem with that is that the items inside each of these widgets need their own grid because items need to be at some given coordinates and have transforms inside the widget, etc. I am not sure how this could function, since there doesn't seem to be any such QGraphicsLayout that would allow this. This also kind of means each widget would need its own QGraphicsScene. I am not sure how to achieve this.

Can a QGraphicsWidget even have its own scene or does it *have* to access the shared main scene? If it had to access the shared scene, then each widget would need to be aware of where it was, which seems silly.

I don't need an implementation, just a clarification of how I would go about achieving this with QGraphicsWidgets. Or is my understanding of the QGraphicsWidget completely off?

Comment: [Lots to read here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/graphicsview.html#the-graphics-view-coordinate-system). You probably can place each widget at the wanted position in your unique scene and then use the item coordinates to draw everything inside the widget so it will be relative to the widget position in the scene.

Comment: Thanks, if I understand correctly, it is possible to place e.g. three widgets on the same scene and have each use their own coordinate system?

Comment: Yes. As the doc says Qt uses 3 referential centres for the coordinates. You can draw/transform/whatever your custom item based on its own centre (0,0) and Qt will paint each item relatively to the item position in the scene, based on the scene coordinate system.
That means the (0,0) for the functions inside the widget can actually be (10,100) or (100,10) on the scene widget. The translation is implicit.